# Get names of all columns with StringType

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I get all column names where datatype is not StringType?
I have:

```
dt = [(10,20,50, 'Big'), 
        (4,5,20,'Small'), 
        (3,1,30,'Middle'), 
        (34,100,40,'Any') 
      ]
dtColumns = ["valA","valB", "valC","text"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=dt, schema = dtColumns)
    
for f in df.schema.fields:
       if f !='StringType':
          print(df.columns)
```

But this doesn't work. I am still receiving also StringTypes and also duplicates.

```
Result:
    ['valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'text']
    ['valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'text']
    ['valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'text']
    ['valA', 'valB', 'valC', 'text']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.dtypes` if you want string comparaison:

```
non_string_cols = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t !='string']

print(non_string_cols)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the `dataType` of the field to the Spark datatype `StringType`, not comparing to a string.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

not_string = [c.name for c in df.schema.fields if not isinstance(c.dataType, StringType)]

print(not_string)
# ['valA', 'valB', 'valC']
```